# Check if the URL ends with Image Ext

Tags: php, regex

I have this `preg_match()` here checking of the inputted value is a `URL` or not.

```
$regex = '_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "It is an Image URL";
} else {
    echo "It is not an Image URL";
}
```

I took it from [Here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) Since it is clearly has the best validation results,  It is too long And i'm not so expert in RegEx So i've tried to add a part where it checks if the URL ends with an image extension

So i've added the following rule `.(?:jpg|gif|png)` right before `?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS` part, But didn't work, What is the mistake i made exactly?

Comment: Did you try `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` instead of this monstrosity?

Comment: If you want to only allow these three extensions add the following after `$`: `(?<=\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)`. However, a regex is not the best way to deal with URL validation.

Comment: @baldrs In the URL i mentioned https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex they statics tells that this regex is better for validation than `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the proper tools for the job:

```
$exts = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');

if(filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) &&
   in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $exts)) {
        echo "It is an Image URL";
} else {
        echo "It is NOT an Image URL";
}
```

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) has many validate filters and [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) can return information about the path.

Comment: Exactly what I've meant by use `filter_var`

Comment: Does `pathinfo` works by checking the `HEAD`? Since i don't want any chance for `DDoS` attacks.

Comment: HEAD of the document or HTTP headers?  No, it parses the path to give you parts of it.  Check the link.